# How to unittest (assert) tuple containing list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a tuple:

```
expected = (list, string)
```

The first argument is a list and the second is string.

The list items can have any order. Usually when asserting a list I would do `assertCountEqual()` which checks the items irrespective or order. How to unit test tuple containing list?

Comment: I don't think you can with a built-in method. Why don't you simply split the tuple in two and compare the two different elements accordingly?

Comment: Test 2 things in one unit test? How can we achieve this?

Comment: You can put how many `assert` you want in a single test. Note that when we say "a test should only test one thing", doesn't actually mean that each test must have a single assert statement. Sometimes the thing you want to test is a relatively complex condition and you have to choose between simply using an `assertTrue` with a huge expression, or just split the assert into multiple subcomponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def assertMyTupleEqual(self, expected, actual):
    self.assertEqual(type(expected), type(actual))  # check they are the same type
    self.assertEqual(len(expected), len(actual))  # check they are the same length
    self.assertEqual(expected[1], actual[1])  # check they have the same string
    self.assertCountEqual(expected[0], actual[0])  # check they have the same list
```